# find-command for certain subdirectories

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find

Let's say I have a directory `dir` with three subdirectories `dir1` .. `dir3`. And inside I have many files and other subdirectories.

I'd like to search for a file inside, say with a `*.c` ending, but I'd only like to search in subdirectory "dir/dir2" and all its subdirectories. How can I formulate that?

Assuming I'm in `dir/` I have:

`find . -name "*.c"`

to search in all directories.

How do I restrict to only `dir2`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Find will accept any valid path so

```
find ./dir2 -name '*.c'
```

should do the trick

If the `dir` directory is `/home/user/dir` you could give find the full path

```
find /home/user/dir/dir2 -name '*.c'
```

Answer (score 38):

You could also use the `-path` parameter of `find` in place of `-name`:

```
find . -path "dir2/*.c"
```

This could allow you to find files in `dir2` even if `dir2` were not a direct subdirectory, E.G:

```
# find . -path "*/dir2/*.c"
./dir_a/dir2/file.c
./dir_b/dir2/file.c
```

Answer (score 7):

You can do `find dir2 -name '*.c'`

You could also do `(cd dir2; find . -name '*.c')`

If you wanted to look at `dir1` and `dir3` but not `dir2`, you could do `find dir1 dir3 -name '*.c'`

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are in `dir`

```
find dir2 -name '*.c'
```

of course [Iain's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/591/iain) [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4864/find-command-for-certain-subdirectories/4865#4865) is also correct

Answer (score -1):

When searching a set of **subdirectories** specified using a **wildcard**, do **not** use the `-path` flag as it can be slow.

```bash
tree findtest/
```

```
findtest/
|-- dir_1_
|-- dir_2_
|   `-- file_2_
|-- dir_3_
|   |-- dir_3_1_
|   `-- dir_3_2_
|       `-- file_3_2_
`-- file_0_

5 directories, 3 files
```

(NB The current directory contains many other files and subdirectories.)

Slow using a subdirectory wildcard in '-path':

```bash
time find . -path "./findtest/dir_*_/file_*_"
```

```
./findtest/dir_2_/file_2_
./findtest/dir_3_/dir_3_2_/file_3_2_
0.084u 0.699s 0:17.84 4.3%      0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w
```

Faster alternative:

```bash
time find ./findtest/dir_*_/ -name "file_*_"
```

```
./findtest/dir_2_/file_2_
./findtest/dir_3_/dir_3_2_/file_3_2_
0.000u 0.002s 0:00.00 0.0%      0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w
```

Comment: Translating your suggestion to use `find ./findtest/dir_*_/ -name "file_*_"` into something using the terms that the user is using in the question, you get `find dir2 -name '*.c'`. This is repeated in most answers already. The rest of your answer seems to be a comment on Josh's answer (?).