# How do I search all subdirectories to find one with a certain name?

Tags: filesystems, find, directory, directory-structure

Let's say I have a top level directory called `/dir` and many sub directories. How do I search the subdirectories of `/dir` to find the one called `x/x/dir/x/x/x/target`?

This question is similar to, but not exactly what I am looking for: [find command for certain subdirectories](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4864/find-command-for-certain-subdirectories).

I am not looking for files, just directories with a particular name.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try `find /dir -type d -name "your_dir_name"`.

Replace `/dir` with your directory name, and replace `"your_dir_name"` with the name you're looking for.

`-type d` will tell `find` to search for directories only.

Comment: And, to search all the directories, replace `/dir` with... `.`.

Answer (score 2):

For a more general solution of finding one or more directories and searching them for something like finding old email addresses in git repositories look at the following pattern:

```
find . -type d -name .git -print0|\
    xargs -0r -I {} find {} -type f -print0 |\
    xargs -0r grep -e 'my.old@email.address'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo **/target
```

or to get one match per line:

```
printf %s\\n **/target
```

This works out of the box in zsh. In bash, you need to run `shopt -s globstar` first, and beware that this also traverses symbolic links to directories. In ksh93, you need to run `set -o globstar` first.

If you want to match only directories or symbolic links to directories, add a trailing `/` (i.e. `**/target/`). In zsh, to match only directories but not symbolic links to directories, make that `**/target(/)`.

In any shell, you can use the `find` command:

```
find . -name target
```

On Linux and Cygwin, the `.` is optional. If you want to match only directories, add `-type d`.